# Как появилось слово «февраль»?

Tags: этимология, фонетика, историческая-грамматика

Известно, что изначально название зимнего месяца имело другую форму, близкую к первоисточнику: *февра**р**ь*, однако впоследствии изменилась в текущую *февра**л**ь*.

Почему произошло это изменение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вряд ли на вопрос "Почему?" тут можно дать ответ иной, чем "так народ его обкатал". Тем более, что переход произошол во времена седой древности, "февруарь" встречается как регулярное только в первых русских летописях, написанных во времена, когда еще в русском были живы славянские названия месяцев. Непривычное слово могли обкатать как угодно.

Другое дело, насколько подобный переход вообще характерен для русского. И тут надо признать, что звук Р в заимствованиях вообще сильно неустойчив в русском, достаточно часто заменяется на Л.
Колидор вместо коридор, лыцарь вместо рыцарь - и проч.

Одним из действующих факторов, видимо, была диссимиляция двух фонетически "трудных" звуков Р в одном слове.

Вот [тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=sd1dAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=OoJ-On1g3k&sig=V8rCb236IONKoJ47THke-YJ123A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA1tXv8IbdAhVjqYsKHQvACVI4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false) есть более подробно, но не более, к сожалению, информативно.

В качестве диссимилирующего катализатора указано соответствие в славянских языках, например, там, где в польском РЖ (орфографическое RZ), там с большим основанием можно ожидать в русском перехода Л<Р. Но это чисто мнение автора, тут, скорее, связано с тем, что западнославянское РЖ - это рефлекс несостоявшейся палатализации Р перед гласными переднего ряда. А в русском в Л чаще переходит именно мягкое Р (то есть и Л тоже мягкое).

Все это в общем-то лишь соображения по поводу. Реального объяснения "почему", как сказал, тут я не вижу.

Comment: Это и есть реальное объяснение. Трудно нам выговаривать два Р, да еще если первое твердое, через один гласный. Таких и слов-то в русском нету. Перерыв? -- здесь первый Р мягкий. Раритет? -- нерусское, и выговаривается с трудом.

Comment: @Niemand  "Реальное объяснение" как ответ на вопрос "почему" предполагает установление причинно-следственной связи хотя бы на уровне гипотезы. ну нельзя же всерьез утверждать, что ветер дует, потому что деревья шатаются.

Comment: А Мягкое и твердое Р подряд выговариваются еще мене свободно. Но это вообще уже не в кассу разговора. Смотрите текст ответа. именно мягкое Р более подвержено переходы в ЛЬ.

Comment: Поправьте "произошол". И да, диссимиляция.

Comment: др.-русск. феврарь, феуларь, ст.-слав. февруарь https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%84/%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

Исключительно к вопросу корней слова: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]